# Google Maps SDK for iOS latest version for manual installation

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I get the following XCode 9.0 compiler warning:

> New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS
>   available: 2.4.30121.0

But the latest available version for manual installation I see on the Google Maps API page [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) is version 2.4.0. Can someone please point me to the very latest version for download (not for CocoaPods)?

Answer (score 1):

On the same [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) page it is mentioned that :

> Note: Versions 1.9.2 and earlier of the Google Maps SDK for iOS were available as a zip file containing a static framework. There was also the option to install recent versions from a CocoaPods pod. From version 1.10.0 onwards, the Google Maps SDK for iOS is available for installation only via CocoaPods.

So you can install version 1.9.2 manually

Comment: This is clearly a mistake. On the same page there is a link to download the SDK source files for GoogleMaps-2.4.0.

Comment: @declan also note if you download the source files there is no "GoogleMaps.bundle" file .... which is required

Comment: GoogleMaps.bundle is there. As per the instructions for manual installation : * Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder. * Then drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder into your project.